# Arguments in theories for Eternal Return

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, universe

Are there any ideas in physics which support the argument for eternal return?
I am looking for any mathematical structure supporting observations which could be in support of a cyclical Universe.

I know that Nietzsche's arguments on this were based on classical physics which is now obsolete.

Some things which I could think of which would go in favor of eternal return are:
One which I could think of is that the Universe might not be entirely governed by mathematical rules, or math might not be complete in a sense.( I know this is not physics, and I am looking for physics answers).
There could be a different kind of logic at the base of it all, making time circular.
I cannot however think of an argument through physics for it currently.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_return
Eternal return (also known as "eternal recurrence") is a concept that the universe and all existence and energy has been recurring, and will continue to recur, in a self-similar form an infinite number of times across infinite time or space.

Comment: If the universe is infinite, everything will happen an infinite number of times.

Comment: But there could be infinite patterns as well.

Comment: What *is* the argument for eternal return?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_return : Eternal return (also known as "eternal recurrence") is a concept that the universe and all existence and energy has been recurring, and will continue to recur, in a self-similar form an infinite number of times across infinite time or space.

Comment: "But there could be infinite patterns as well" Yes indeed : everything, with or without patterns, will happen infinitely often - IF the universe is infinite.

Comment: @hdhondt so it's not widely accepted that the universe is infinite?

Comment: @safesphere Thanks! So are there any ideas which say the Universe could repeat itself without making use of the concept of infinity?

Comment: Yes, like here (just replace any reference to "infinite" with more careful "indefinite" or something like that): https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_model

Comment: @safesphere : I will accept that as an answer, if you wish to post it. Thanks!

Comment: Though for eternal return, we need the exact set of events to repeat.

Comment: This is not physics. Why is this site allowing non standard xxxx to be posted in this site. I thought it did not even allow nonstandard physics.     Is there a bias fro some crazy theories, but not for some somewhat speculative physics theories? Vote to close.

Comment: @BobBee Do you consider the Steinhardt-Turok and Baum-Frampton cosmological modes to be "some crazy speculative theories" of nonstandard physics? Cause , if you did, I'd actually agree :)

Comment: novice, it's not that I asked for the definition of eternal return, it's that I asked for the *argument* for eternal return.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri At this point, nothing short of a flaw in the assumption of causality.

Comment: @safesphere. No, those cosmological models were based on physics ideas, even if they seemed somewhat different.In general the cyclic universe possibility, with various means/assumptions on how they can be,may not be the standard cosmological model, but I think they've not been definitely disproven, so they are fair, if unlikely possibilities. Still, I do not understand how the currently known values of the expansion and acceleration be reconciled with a return to a Big Bounce.How would the acceleration become negative? But Nietzsche or nonsense as in the referenced wiki article is not physics

Comment: @BobBee Nietzsche's position was certainly not physics. It was a philosophical position based on classical physics, which is redundant today.

Comment: Not redundant, just a low energy low speed macroscopic approximation to be more exact. My point is that the wiki article is mostly not the physics of the cyclic models, but generic discussion of eternal return philosophical discussions over the years. Not redundant, but obsolete for those purposes.

Comment: @BobBee I agree. I haven't studied Nietzsche, but when I see "infinite", I just stop reading, because this concept is widely misunderstood. Same with this Wiki. IMO, if the universe is in some sense "cyclic", then it's not because of some random occurrence in an "infinite" set, but because of a deterministic process. Just add another dimension to the curvature. Imagine a 1D universe as a circle of a latitude parallel on the globe expanding from a point at the North Pole down. After a while it would shrink back to a point at the South Pole. Now just add 2 more dimensions for the Big Crunch :)

Comment: @BobBee Just fyi, I can't find anything in the timeline indicating you actually voted to close as you claim in one comment here. If you think this question should be off-topic as non-mainstream, please actually vote to close to enqueue it into the close review queue - I just now stumbled across it by accident.

Comment: @BobBee I am not saying that Eternal return is true, just looking for physics theories which might support it, knowing well that the mainstream does not favor it.

Comment: @CuriousMind. I could not find it in the Close que. Just tried, probably should have before. Is there a way to find it now?

Comment: @BobBee You can press a button to (vote to) close it. It's near edit.

Comment: @wizwizz4. Probably will next time, never felt that closing was a particularly good answer to crackpots and that labeling them that way would be more instructive to the community, but I do understand understand why policy-wise it's better to close.

Comment: Given Tegmark's 2003 paper at https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0302131, as well as Vilenkin's 2011 paper at https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.4990, I really cannot understand the frenzy in favor of closing this question.  Was something relevant to it discovered between 2011 and 2017 that I didn't hear about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nietzsche's "argument", for those who don't know it, was that there must be only finitely many possible physical configurations, and that the notion of a beginning of time is unscientific, and so therefore, the universe is eternal, and every physical situation must recur eternally in it.

Of course, he was writing before general relativity and Hubble's discovery of universal expansion. The only time I have seen a modern physicist mention this argument from Nietzsche, was in Frank Tipler's *The Physics of Immortality*, where it is presented as the alternative to Tipler's own cosmology, in which a computer-god at the end of time resurrects (via simulation) everyone who ever lived.

But as for whether there are any cosmological models taken seriously now, that imply eternal recurrence, whether deterministic or probabilistic... The big bounce of the ekpyrotic universe gets some media, but not so much attention from the community. Anti de Sitter space *does* imply quantum Poincare recurrence, but isn't taken seriously as a model of reality (unless you could somehow have a de Sitter fluctuation within it).

Anti de Sitter space does illustrate another way you could get a de facto recurrence: you could simply make the time coordinate periodic, so that, rather than the future recapitulating the past, time just "goes in a circle" and the far future is literally also the distant past. Periodic time is a common construct in mathematical physics, but I can't think of any cosmology that is taken seriously and which applies periodic time to the real world. The Goedel universe has this feature, but isn't a serious cosmological model. Maybe you could do this in Penrose's conformal cyclic cosmology, but again, that's a model which exists more in media coverage than as an object of research.

**HOWEVER!** If we look slightly afield, and ask whether there are scenarios under consideration in which our lives are repeated infinitely throughout space and time, though perhaps not serially, then we come much closer to the mainstream of research.

I believe the core area where this issue arises is in the study of what is called "the measure problem" in cosmology. The measure problem concerns the difficulty of extracting observational predictions in a cosmology that contains infinitely many observers. A probability is a kind of expected frequency of occurrence, so you need to be able to count observers and then say what fraction of them have a particular observation; but when space and time are infinite, these numbers may both be just "infinity", so you are dealing with infinity divided by infinity.

There are ways around this; for example, you may start within a finite volume of space-time, in which numbers are finite and you can define finite ratios, and then you can look at the asymptotic behavior of those ratios as you widen the scope to infinity. But meanwhile, it is incidentally the case, in an infinite universe (or "multiverse") of the kind implied by eternal inflation, that the physical state of our observable region (our Hubble volume) will be repeated infinitely often.

A rather less mainstream scenario, in which infinite duplication may also occur, is the Boltzmann brain problem.

The Boltzmann brain problem is that in an eternally expanding de Sitter universe, even after the expansion has completely attenuated the matter of the universe, the quantum fields will continue to fluctuate, and over infinite time will produce (with appropriately minute, but still greater-than-zero, probability) every physically possible configuration of matter. Only some people are bothered by this, but papers do get written about it.

Comment: Thank you . That Anti De Sitter thing was exactly what I was looking for.!

Comment: @novice Then perhaps you should make a quick edit to your question to clarify for the readers what exactly you were looking for?

Comment: @safesphere A possible mathematical structure where a cyclical Universe is possible. Edited.